# dayjs timeZone is not supported

Tags: react-native, dayjs

I'm trying to use Timezone with dayjs in my react-native project, as described in the documntation
I needed to import the utc and timezone plugin.

```
import tz from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';


dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(tz);
```

but actually when I started using it, it give me an error Timezone is not supported

```
 console.log( dayjs('2013-11-18 11:55').tz('America/Toronto'), 'timezone');
```

the error below is showing from Intl package that I'm using in the project

[image: screenshot of error]

I have tried to update the dayjs package,the intl-react package and intl package itself, couldn't found any solution to this problem with react native, I still don't get what is missing here ?

Comment: Are you using React Native Hermes engine ? 
There seems to be an issue about that:
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1377

Comment: yeah, I saw it, but is it normal to add 9 packages to just solve this problem? no sense at all

Comment: still a problem up until now

Comment: yes, I switched to moment already way way better

Comment: @Hamed Does everything related with tz works well out of the box with moment?